# PHP: How to display count from 1 to infinity as title per div?

Tags: php

I have a series of repeatable div's where the user can go in and add as many as they want, I just want to number the div's. The idea I have now is to use PHP to count them and echo the number from 1 to infinity with 1 being the first div and so on.

I'm not sure how this works, but I think we have to start with some math?

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
```

...and then something about `foreach div.tiles-wrap echo $i + 1`...?

```
    <div class="tiles-horizontal">
        <div class="tiles-wrap">
            <div class="title"><p class="center"><?php echo i; ?></p></div>
            <div class="image"><img src="#" /></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: just place a counter flag(which will be incremented) in your foreach loop, after completion of loop, you'll have the count in that flag. Instead of $i + 1 , use $i++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After display count number in each div you need to increment $i value, like this:

```
<div class="tiles-horizontal">
    <div class="tiles-wrap">
        <div class="title"><p class="center"><?php echo $i; ++$i;?></p></div>
        <div class="image"><img src="#" /></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, you can short that down into this:

`<?= $i++ ?>` or `<?= ++$i ?>` depending on when the variable shout be incremented.

This echoes `$i`, and then increments it by 1 for the next time.

Comment: It's bad advice, because this short tag may be removed in future versions of php. 
Just read this. http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/151661/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-tag-in-php

Comment: I don't see a problem using it. I've read the article you linked. The only argument is: `What if it gets removed?`. yeah... Then we can't use anything from PHP, since every function WILL at some point become deprecated / removed. I'd say, use it if you want to. Besides - IF they removes it, it takes less than 5 minutes to replace `<?=` with `<?php echo`. But i do understand your concern :)

Comment: So far this isn't working for me... I put <?php $i = 0; ?> at the top and <?php echo $i; ++$i;?> in the title for the div. The test url is http://www.mrobertsdesign.ca/products/water_wallmounted_stone.php am I doing this right? The value just shows as 0.

Comment: You need to put `<?php $i = 0; ?>` at the top of page once, not at the top of div.

Comment: That is what I was doing, the value is still 0, I've been playing with it for a while can't get any math going unfortunately.

Comment: It's an issue with a cms I'm using, the php variable is loading before the cms loads the repeatable regions so the variable will always stay at 0 - any chance we can add a timer or something and see what happens?

Comment: Don't know, it's strange cms.
It's no timers in php

Answer (score 0):

Put:

```
<?php $i++; ?>
```

at the bottom of the loop body to increment the counter variable.

Answer (score 0):

This really is not any kind of math problem just very simple programming. If you wish to accomplish this with php you will need something like
Lets say you have a button they press each time they wish to add another div in php we take care of it like this:
Forgot to add we need a Session variable to keep track of it

```
 if(isset($_POST['submitbutton']))
        $_SESSION['count']++;
```

...

After you only need to do a for loop and echo out as many div's as you need like this

```
<?php for($i=0; $i<$_SESSION['count'];$i++): ?>
   <div>
     <p> Div Number <?php echo $i ?> </p>
   </div>
<?php endfor ?>
```

And thats it you may also need to add a button like this :

```
<form action="" method="POST">
   <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Click to add div" />
</form>
```